# Spring y Angular 4 - Generar Archivos Blob o Base64

Tags: java, spring, angular

disculpen la molestia espero me puedan ayudar con mi consulta! 
Estoy desarrollando en una plataforma que en el `front` tiene `Angular 4`
y el `Back` es `Spring`, 
En el `front` utilizo un `npm` que se llama `pdf make`,  y me genera los `pdf` en una ventana o se descargan automáticamente, ocupo que cuando se genere guardarlo en mi servidor para que posteriormente puedan hacer uso de el. 
`PdfMake` me permite generar un `blob` o un `base64` al generar el `pdf`, puedo capturar toda la `cadena` del documento, pero no se como mandarlo al `back` para que mi `back` ya haga la creación del documento y lo guarde!

Estaba viendo que con `URL.createObjet` (algo así), 
pero realmente desconozco como mandarlo! 
Si pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería.

Comment: No acabo de entenderlo: quieres crear un PDF en *front* para guardarlo en *back* o para que el usuario lo descargue? ¿O ambas cosas, guardar una copia en back cuando el usuario quiera generarlo?

Comment: Realmente el pdf, ya se genera con la librería de pdfmake, solo que cuando se genera lo manda a una url especifica, pero pdfmake tiene una función que puedes obtener el buffer o base64, Exactamente solo ocupo que el archivo generado por cadena, (base64), ya guardarlo en el back como un documento, para posteriormente poder descargarlo desde otra parte! 
No se si me explique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes un objeto Blob, es tan sencillo como hacer:

```
sendPdf(pdf: Blob) {
  this.http.post(URL,pdf);
}
```

donde `http` es una instancia de `HttpClient`

Para recibirlo debería valerte algo como

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Long> uploadAvatar(@RequestParam MultipartFile  avatar) {
    byte[] bytes = avatar.getBytes();
}
```

Comment: Y al capturarlo en el back?, le mando el post(blob, '/api/ruta/') 
Pero lo que se tiene en el back para subir archivos normalemente, no funciona y si imprimo en consola el HttpServletRequest

Documento recibido SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper@5703e1d9]

Comment: Mira a ver si eso te sirve...